# HTML encoding issue in azure devops extension

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I'm working on an hub `ms.vss-web.hub` extension for azure devops and I'm facing emoji rendering issue *(text is within a diff [monaco text editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/))*

[image]

looking at the html source, the emoji is not rendered as well
[image]

during development, I was using baseUri (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#runtime-attributes) and it was working as expected.

(below, display & source in devops, but with extension served from my laptop)
[image]

- emoji rendering is failing in all parts of the page, not only monaco editor (I would exclude monaco editor from suspects)
- html page is correctly in UTF8
- I've checked html page after `tfx extension create` process (unzip) and encoding & emoji were still ok

I suspect an intermediate process done by devops while rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forced `UTF8 with BOM` rather only `UTF8` and it fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: can do :) hope it can help.